# Regex to validate Apple Bundle Identifier

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate Apple Bundle Identifier in javascript which is of the form com.somecompany.appname. What should be the regular expression for this ?

Comment: bundle IDs aren't guaranteed to start with com only. For example VLC starts with org.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
/com\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/
```

Comment: A bundle id doesn't have to start with com, can contain dashes `-`, underscores `_`, digits and more than 3 terms separated by dots

Answer (score 2):

As it said SLdragon but with regexp should start and end with this pattern.

`/^[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)+$/ig`

Answer (score 1):

The bundle ID is not required start with "com", and allow to include dash "-", so you can use this regex to match them:

> /^[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*/i

Comment: This would match `o_o` which is invalid. Something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+$` would work for the following (unfortunately) valid bundle identifiers according to Xcode 12: `...`, `---`.